# grep + FIND all files that are jar files and ended with jar

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep

With this way we can get all .jar files list:

```
#  su -l hdfs -c " hdfs dfs -ls /home/test/jt/*.jar "
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs     501879 2019-03-04 10:35 /home/test/jt/cfjrfr-3.8.1.jar
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs     870215 2019-03-04 10:35 /home/test/jt/dhe-1.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs    2734339 2019-03-04 10:35 /home/test/jt/34343-25.1-jre.jar
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs      30053 2019-03-04 10:35 /home/test/jt/23424.jar
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs      16481 2019-03-04 10:35 /home/test/jt/h324.jar
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs      29725 2019-03-04 10:35 /home/test/jt/3223kj3.jar
```

We try also different approach with grep, but this syntax does not return any output:

```
 su -l hdfs -c " hdfs dfs -ls /home/test/jt" |  grep  "*.jar$"
```

**Where I am wrong?**

Comment: Well, for one thing you are confusing regex and glob patterns: if you want to grep for lines ending in `.jar` try `grep  "\.jar$"`

Comment: but what about all words before .jar , so why not set *\.jar$

Comment: (a) first it's incorrect, you would need `.*\.jar` and (b) second it's superfluous because `grep` outputs whole lines when a match is found (unless you are using `-o` for example)

Comment: Why are you using `su`? What is `hdfs`? Basically, why aren't you just running `ls /home/test/jt/*.jar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is excessful here. In regular expressions, `*` is used to specify that the previous symbol can appear any number of times, including 0. Using it without a preceding symbol is pointless, so in this special case `grep` looks for the `*` symbol itself (in general case you need to precede it with `\` for this purpose).

`.` has a special meaning of matching any symbol too, so if you want to cover the situations where there are some bogus extensions like `.djar`, or extensionless files ending with `jar`, you need to precede it with `\` too.

So, in short, you need just:

```
su -l hdfs -c " hdfs dfs -ls /home/test/jt" |  grep  "\.jar$"
```

Comment: but what about all words before  .jar , so why not set *\.jar$

Comment: If you don't care about them, why specify them in the expression?  Also, in RE, `*` is meaningless without a character class before it; `*` means "zero or more of the previous match".

Comment: ... at least with GNU grep, BRE treats a leading `*` a literal, whereas ERE treats it as zero or more occurrences of a leading empty string (which matches everything)

Comment: @yael `grep` searches for a substring by default. It doesn't care about other symbols if there is enough consequent symbols to match the given pattern. If you want it to match the whole line, the expression should both start with `^` and end with `$`. In this case, if you want to make sure that file has an actual name besides of the extension, you can check it with `[^/]\.jar$`, which means that any symbol except of directory separator (`/`) can appear before the dot. `[^` symbol `]` is an inversion operator.

Answer (score 0):

With grep -E

```
su -l hdfs -c " hdfs dfs -ls /home/test/jt" |  grep  -E .jar$
```

It searches in the output of first command all files that end with .jar

Comment: No, that will find all lines that end in "any character" _then_ `jar`. For example `fajar`.  You want `grep '\.jar$`. But in any case, this is the same as what the OP already did. The `-E` doesn't make any difference at all here.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
ls -l | grep *.jar*
```

Comment: Apart from the problems with parsing the output of ls, this will also find names like `foojarbar`. Why not just `ls -l *.jar`?

Comment: @terdon "ls -l * .jar " will list all files with .doc at the at the end if you wanna list ALL files speicfically which have ".jar" you should use " ls -l * .jar * " this specfically looks for th phrase ".jar" instead of only jar.

Comment: I know the formatting here is complicated. Sorry! Please look at the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) help page for help on formatting your posts.

Comment: yea the format is pretty annoying

Comment: @terdon: I invite you to take a deep breath and reread the comments you wrote (above), remembering that glob ≠ ``grep``.

Comment: @Qasim: If you’re talking about `ls ` *`(options) (some_other_directory) `* `|  grep *.jar*`, you’re mixing dynamite and plutonium — it’s going to blow up, badly.

Comment: @G-Man Where do globs enter into this? I said that `grep .jar` will find any input line containing the string `jar` and one other character before it. That's because `.` means "any character" in regular expressions, nothing to do with globs. What am I missing? (also note that my coments were written for the first version of this answer, which only showed `grep .jar*, but the point still stands).

Comment: @G-Man sorry im kind of a noob at linux, i try to learn everyday, also i will use the '< and >' symbol to represnt a peice of terminal code in this comment, anyways what i was meant to say was that <ls *.jar> will list all files that end in .jar, but <ls *.jar*> will list all files with the words '.jar. specifically and not any files that have 'jar' in them, only files that have '.jar' in them

Comment: @G-Man also i have no idea what globs are as i said im a noob mabye when i improve my linux knowledge use i will understand, also if anyone here knows anything about process prioritys please answer my question.

Comment: @G-Man Interesting how things are so much clearer after a good nights sleep. You're quite right, of course, `ls *.jar` will list files ending in `.jar`. My point about the regex was because the OP was using `ls | grep .jar` and that does something very different. I just copied the wrong thing into my comment.